# How to append a selection of a numpy array to an empty numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I have a three .txt files to which I have successfully made into a numpy array. If you are curious these files are [Level 2](http://www.srl.caltech.edu/ACE/ASC/level2/index.html) data from the Advanced Composition Experiment (ACE). The particular files are found in the MAG and SWEPAM sections and are 16 second average and 64 second average, respectively. The data in a nut shell is representative of the z-component magnetic field of an inbound particle field, its constituents by measure of counts per area, and its velocity. Currently the focus of the study is on inbound hydrogen, but I digress. The code is as follows I use to read and save the files (as well as fix any errors) is provided below:

```
Bz = np.loadtxt(r"/home/ary/Desktop/Arya/Project/Data/AC/MAG/ACE_MAG_Data_SEPT_18_2015.txt", dtype = bytes).astype(float)
SWEPAM_HV = np.loadtxt(r"/home/ary/Desktop/Arya/Project/Data/ACE/SWEPAM/Proton_Density/ACE_SWEPAM_H_Density_20150918.txt", dtype = bytes).astype(float)
SWEPAM_HD = np.loadtxt(r"/home/ary/Desktop/Arya/Project/Data/ACE/SWEPAM/Proton_Speed/ACE_SWEPAM_H_Velocity_20150918.txt",dtype = bytes).astype(float)

Bz = np.ma.masked_array(Bz, Bz <= -999, fill_value = 0)
SWEPAM_HD = np.ma.masked_array(SWEPAM_HD, SWEPAM_HD <= -999, fill_value = 0)
SWEPAM_HV = np.ma.masked_array(SWEPAM_HV, SWEPAM_HV <= -999, fill_value = 0)

Mag_time = np.arange(0,86400, 16, dtype = float)
SWEPAM_time = np.arange(0,86400,64, dtype = float)
```

However, within these array I am particularly interested in only the 1349th position to the 2024th position. These numbers are of interest because of my investigation into an anomaly which happened between these two points. So I figured the following would lead me to success. To which it hasn't and many variations have failed too. I present to you the most recent script I have right now:

```
Mag_time_prime = np.array([])
Bz_prime = np.array([])
for i in range(1349,2024):
    append(Mag_time_prime,Mag_time[i]).astype(float)
    append(Bz_prime,Bz[i]).astype(float)
print(Mag_time_prime.shape)
print(Bz_prime.shape)
```

I had figured that by making empty arrays (I did try `np.empty(0)` for the primes and couldn't get that to work for me) that I could just make a for loop to locate and append the `i_th` position from the `Bz` and `Mag_time` to the empty 'prime' arrays within the specified range. However the 'prime' arrays have continuously popped out empty arrays. So my question, where have I gone wrong and how should I fix it?

Comment: **Do not use `numpy.append`**.  If you must append, use lists.  And if you must use the array append, use it as documented,

Comment: How have I not used `numpy.append` as intended? The documentation says the first position is for the list you want to append to and the second the value you wish to append to that list. The list I want to append is one of the primes and the value I wish to append to it is the i_th position of the respective array.

Comment: But `np.append`returns a value, the concatenation of 2 arrays.  `alist.append()` changes `alist` (in-place).  That's big reason why I say don't use it.  People mistakenly use it as if it were a list append.

Comment: Oh, are you implying that the concatenation of the empty array (any of the prime arrays) with any other array would still return an empty array? Analogously speaking, is it similar to how the **0** vector dotted into any vector gives the **0** vector?

Answer (score 0):

List append acts on the list itself:

```
In [1]: alist = []
In [2]: alist.append(5)
In [3]: alist.append(3)
In [4]: alist
Out[4]: [5, 3]
```

`np.append` does not change its arguments:

```
In [5]: arr = np.array([])
In [6]: np.append(arr,1)
Out[6]: array([ 1.])
In [7]: np.append(arr,2)
Out[7]: array([ 2.])
In [8]: arr
Out[8]: array([], dtype=float64)
```

You have to assign the value of `append` back to `arr` to get the list equivalent behavior:

```
In [9]: arr=np.append(arr,1)
In [10]: arr=np.append(arr,2)
In [11]: arr
Out[11]: array([ 1.,  2.])
```

Each time you use `np.append` you create a new copy (it uses `np.concatenate`).  For one or two times that's ok, but if done repeatedly it is inefficient.

The preferred way is to use list append to build a list, and then make an array from that:

```
In [12]: np.array(alist)
Out[12]: array([5, 3])
```

You have to understand `np.concatenate` before you can use `np.append` properly.  It is a poor substitute for list append.